# Joining tables that have different numbers of rows using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, raster-attribute-table

I am trying to join a table to a raster output for an assignment in ArcMap (10.7), but they both have different numbers of rows.

Is it possible to join them?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  What happened when you tried to do this?  How precisely did you try to do this?  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that. Start with the table that has the greater number of rows and to it join the table with the fewest rows. Be sure 'keep only matching records' is not checked.

A common situation similar to yours is where you might have a feature table with many features classified into 5 'Types'. To that table you want to join a much smaller dictionary-like table that has only 5 rows; one for each Type along with a definition and/or associated attributes. The resulting table has all of the original rows where each row has the extra fields with the appropriately matched up values depending on Type.